# How can I get a certain value in a list and update this value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
print("Hello! We have the following products in stock: ")
print(" ")
stock = [
  {"Product#1": "Donuts", "Price": 17.00, "Stock:": 10},
  {"Product#2": "Triki Trakets", "Price": 11.50, "Stock": 15},
  {"Product#3": "Sausages", "Price": 52.00, "Stock": 7},
  {"Product#4": "Cheese", "Price": 65.00, "Stock": 8},
  {"Product#5": "Coke", "Price": 10.50, "Stock": 25},
  {"Product#6": "Gatorade", "Price": 12.00, "Stock": 15}
        ]
def stonk():
  x = 0
  for product in stock:
    for key, value in product.items():
      print(key, value)
      x += 1
      if x % 3 == 0:
        print("___")


stonk()

print(" ")
print("Prices after a 5.5% increase:")
```

The point of this code is to organize in a nice matter data on products in stock and their price. Now that I've arranged the data I need to update it yet I'm not sure how this is done in arrays. How can I increase "prices" by 5.5% using autonomous code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to increase all prices by 5.5%, all you need to do is iterate over your *list*<sup>[NOT array!](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-array-vs-list/)</sup>, and modify each dictionary to update its `"Price"` key:

```
for product in stock:
    product["Price"] *= 1.055
```

---

Unrelated to your original question, but your data structure doesn't quite make sense. Why append an integer to the `"Product..."` key?

1. You already have a list, so it makes no sense to include *another* index inside the item itself.
2. Having a different structure of each dictionary makes it impossible to access the product name without looking at all the keys in the dictionary and finding one that starts with `"Product"`, which defeats the purpose of a dictionary.

Instead, consider renaming those keys to something uniform that describes what property of your product is specified by that value.

```
stock = [
  {"Name": "Donuts", "Price": 17.00, "Stock": 10},
  {"Name": "Triki Trakets", "Price": 11.50, "Stock": 15},
  {"Name": "Sausages", "Price": 52.00, "Stock": 7},
  {"Name": "Cheese", "Price": 65.00, "Stock": 8},
  {"Name": "Coke", "Price": 10.50, "Stock": 25},
  {"Name": "Gatorade", "Price": 12.00, "Stock": 15}
]
```

Now, when you access the dictionaries in your list, you can simply do `item["Name"]` to get the name of each product. To format your output, you could do something like this:

```
print("We have the following items in stock:")
print(f"{'Product':<30s}{'Price':>6s}{'Stock':>6s}")
for item in stock:
    print(f"{item['Name']:<30s}{item['Price']:>6.2f}{item['Stock']:>6d}")
```

which prints:

```
We have the following items in stock:
Product                        Price Stock
Donuts                         17.00    10
Triki Trakets                  11.50    15
Sausages                       52.00     7
Cheese                         65.00     8
Coke                           10.50    25
Gatorade                       12.00    15
```

See the links [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) and [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more information on the f-string syntax, and [python's format specification syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

---

If you want each product to have a "product ID", then include that as a *separate* key for each product.

```
stock = [
  {"Name": "Donuts", "Price": 17.00, "Stock": 10, "id": 1001},
  {"Name": "Triki Trakets", "Price": 11.50, "Stock": 15, "id": 2001},
  {"Name": "Sausages", "Price": 52.00, "Stock": 7, "id": 3002},
  {"Name": "Cheese", "Price": 65.00, "Stock": 8, "id": 4232},
  {"Name": "Coke", "Price": 10.50, "Stock": 25, "id": 5678},
  {"Name": "Gatorade", "Price": 12.00, "Stock": 15, "id": 6000}
]
```

Alternatively, consider changing your *list* `stock` to a *dictionary*, where each key is the product ID.

```
stock_lookup = {item["id"]: item for item in stock}
```

Now, you can lookup a product by its ID in `stock_lookup`:

```
print(stock_lookup[6000]) # {'Name': 'Gatorade', 'Price': 12.0, 'Stock': 15, 'id': 6000}
```